# Studio Code - Turn Off auto-removing whitespace

Tags: typescript

Studio Code doesn't allow me to keep whitespace.
When I press enter to write a new line, it removes all whitespace.

I've tried to find the settings entry about it but I can't find one that works.

[image]

Comment: I suspect you'll have to disable the TypeScript formatter entirely (`typescript.format.enable = false`), I don't think the default one has an option for leaving those spaces alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to disable the TypeScript formatter entirely (`typescript.format.enable = false`), I don't think the default one has an option for leaving those spaces alone.